# bootstrap modal opens 2nd modal confirm before delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, confirm, bootstrap-modal

I have been trying to get this working for some hours now, but I am having trouble, so I really do need some help.

I want to make a confirm-modal with Cancel and Delete buttons that will open a 2nd modal-confirm popup where the user makes the actual delete selection.

For example when the Cancel button (on both confirm-madal pop ups) is selected, I want nothing to happen.

When the user selects the Delete button on the 1st confirm-modal, a 2nd confirm-modal will be displayed with a different message with Cancel and Delete buttons where the actual delete request is undertaken.

The 1st confirm-modal message should be: "Are you sure you want to delete this value?"

The 2nd confirm-modal message should be: "Are you really sure?".

Here is my button code:

```
<a href="{% url x_delete x.id %}" delete-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this value?">Delete</a>
```

Here is my js code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        //START: Delete code.
        $('a[delete-confirm]').click(function(ev) {

            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            if (!$('#deleteConfirmModal').length) {

                $('body').append('<div id="deleteConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button><h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteConfirmLabel">Delete - X</h4></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn-u btn-u-red" id="deleteConfirmOK" onclick="showProgressAnimation();">Delete</a></div></div>');

            }

            $('#deleteConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('delete-confirm'));

            $('#deleteConfirmOK').attr('href', href);

            $('#deleteConfirmModal').modal({show:true});

            return false;

        });
        //FINISH: Delete code.

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does not support multiple modals opened at the same time.

Comment: What about closing the 1st modal-confirm and then opening the 2nd modal-confirm?

Comment: You can probably do that. The way I went about it was replacing the modal contents with jquery's .html()

Comment: Do you have an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin,    http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/  ,there is a Stackable Modal.